# ajax select which form inputs to post and searlize

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a form using AJAX. How would I select which inputs of the form to send to the code behind (instead of the whole form)?
AJAX

```
  function send()
    {
         $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: this.action,
                    data: {'data1': $('#data1').val(), 
                    'data2': $('#data2').val() },
                    success: function (done) {
            $('#box').html(done.output);
        });
    }
```

FORM

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<input id="data1" value="0" name="data1" onclick="send();" >
<input id="data2" value="0" name="data2" onclick="send();" >

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add your HTML form so that we can help resolve issues you're mentioning below?

Comment: Sure I just added my form. Thanks

Comment: According to me we answered your question "How would I select which inputs of the form to send [...] instead of the whole form?" The above should work. Does it?

Comment: Not hitting the break points in the controller. model property is null. It looks like it should work, but it isn't.

Comment: I suggest starting a new question specifically for C# with some snippets of your C# code. I think Scott Selby was making references to C# however your initial question is mostly targeted towards JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could specify them in the `data` parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: this.action,
    data: { 
        field1: $('#field1').val(), 
        field2: $('#field2').val() 
    }
});
```

Comment: Would I change field1: to the property name it represents in the code behind (model)?

Comment: actually in this code you'd change it to the ID -- for the property name you'd want the selector to be `$('input[name="field1"]')`

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to be hitting my models properties. I am not getting any values back in the code behind.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just added my form.

Comment: Alright, why do you have `onclick` attributes on your input fields?

Comment: But how are you canceling the default event of the button? I don't see you anywhere returning false from this handler. If you don't do this the form will submit normally and your AJAX call will never have the time to ever execute. So do this: `onclick="send(); return false;"`, or even better, don't use any `onclick` attribute in your markup, but use jQuery to subscribe to the `.submit()` event of the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
            var NewKeyword = $('#txtbox1').val();
            var type = $('#txtbox2').val()

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",  
                url: "url...",
                data: "{'type':'" + type + "','keyword' : '" + NewKeyword + "' }",
```

then in c# you have to be able to accept "type and "keyword as parameters in your webmethod

Comment: Very odd doesnt seem to be hitting my models properties. I am not getting any values back in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$form = $('form');
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: this.action,
        data: {
            'name': $('fieldNameForName', $form).val(),
            'age': $('fieldNameForAge', $form).val()
        }
});
```

Comment: Very odd doesn't seem to be hitting my models properties. I am not getting any values back in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using serialize, you could write a function that accepts the form selector:

```
function getFormData(formSelector,toSend){
    var formData = {};
    for(var i in toSend){
        var field = formSelector.find('input[name="'+toSend[i]+'"]');
        if(field!==undefined) formData[toSend[i]] = field[0].val();
    }
    return formData;
}
```

usage:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/myurl'
   data: getFormData($('#myForm'),['FirstName','LastName','FavoriteColor']),
   type: 'POST'
  });
```

The array you pass in should be the name attributes of the fields you want to send (you could make it the id also, or anything else, I just figured you had the name attribute set.

Comment: Very odd doesnt seem to be hitting my models properties. I am not getting any values back in the code behind.